# Why jshell throw Exception at startup at windows when run `jshell` at my home directory?

Tags: java, jshell

When I run jshell 17 / 19 in windows powershell at my home
dir, i.e. `C:\Users\my_user_name`, jshell throws exception as following.

Jdk 19 installed with oracle win10 msi binary, path updated by `$env:PATH='C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin;'+$env:PATH`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Exception during analyze - java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope$StarImportScope.isFilled()" because "tree.starImportScope" is null
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory$AnalyzeTask.analyze(TaskFactory.java:415)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory$AnalyzeTask.<init>(TaskFactory.java:406)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory.lambda$analyze$1(TaskFactory.java:178)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory.lambda$runTask$4(TaskFactory.java:213)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskPool.getTask(JavacTaskPool.java:193)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory.runTask(TaskFactory.java:206)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory.analyze(TaskFactory.java:175)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory.analyze(TaskFactory.java:161)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.Eval.compileAndLoad(Eval.java:1060)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.Eval.declare(Eval.java:893)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.Eval.eval(Eval.java:140)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.JShell.eval(JShell.java:493)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.processSource(JShellTool.java:3624)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.processSourceCatchingReset(JShellTool.java:1348)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.processInput(JShellTool.java:1246)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.run(JShellTool.java:1217)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.startUpRun(JShellTool.java:1178)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.resetState(JShellTool.java:1125)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellTool.start(JShellTool.java:951)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolBuilder.start(JShellToolBuilder.java:261)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.internal.jshell.tool.JShellToolProvider.main(JShellToolProvider.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope$StarImportScope.isFilled()" because "tree.starImportScope" is null
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.analyze(JavacTaskImpl.java:383)
        at jdk.jshell/jdk.jshell.TaskFactory$AnalyzeTask.analyze(TaskFactory.java:412)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.sun.tools.javac.code.Scope$StarImportScope.isFilled()" because "tree.starImportScope" is null
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.TypeEnter.ensureImportsChecked(TypeEnter.java:170)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.complete(Enter.java:628)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Enter.main(Enter.java:588)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.enterTrees(JavaCompiler.java:1042)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.enter(JavacTaskImpl.java:345)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.analyze(JavacTaskImpl.java:399)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$analyze$1(JavacTaskImpl.java:379)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.invocationHelper(JavacTaskImpl.java:152)
        at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.analyze(JavacTaskImpl.java:379)
        ... 21 more
```

But `jshell` works when I first `cd` to any other dir **or** when I use jshell 11 at my home dir.

- Update 1: run with `jshell --no-startup` the `internalError`
  disappeared at startup, but when I type `import java.util.ArrayList;`
  in jshell and type `enter`, `jshell` exits with same the error as
  following.
- Update 2: The error only occured when I execute `jshell` at my home
  dir, i.e. `C:\Users\my_user_name`, but I didn't find out why. (Have
  delete several suspicious folders and files at home dir, still not work). Maybe `jshell` reads something when startup from its `pwd`/`cwd` and get confused by some of my file at home directory ?

Comment: probably because some folder/file used for startup is not accessible to normal users. Maybe it is the startup script, try `jshell --no-startup` or `jshell -`

Comment: Do you have your path setup correctly? If your in the bin folder, then all the files there should be on the path. When you run as administrator, does it have a different path variable than when run as a normal user. ( %PATH% it might be called?)

Comment: @user16320675 `jshell --no-startup` has no error, `jshell -` same error

Comment: @matt I checked `$env:PATH` is correct and same for admin and normal user

Comment: Hi, I updated description, this error seems only occur when I execute `jshell` at my home dir, i.e. `C:\Users\my_user_name`, error disappears when I switch to any other folder at powershell, I had delete several suspicious folders and files at home dir, `jshell` still not work there.

Comment: (1) Maybe the problem is not jshell, maybe it is xxx.jsh content problem. (2) In the user directory, create `Main.jsh`, the content is: `import javax.swing.*;
JFrame f = new JFrame("frame");
JOptionPane. showMessageDialog(f, "Hello Wolrd!");
/exit` (3) Open powershell, execute in the user directory, `jshell --startup Main.jsh`, (4) It can be executed normally, no error message is generated (5) After installing Oracle JDK 19, Windows installer msi, there is no Make any settings, do not set JAVA_HOME or PATH, execute to open powershell, execute jshell directly, and there is no error message.